# How to recover a file which shows [converted] in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file, which accidentally got converted in vim and it shows [converted] at the bottom when opened in vim and it is not human readable. I tried to set the encoding and fileencoding to utf-8 but nothing actually happened. The format remains the same.

Help me with recovering this file please.

Edit-

Here is what I see after I type :set

```
:set
--- Options ---
  bomb                helplang=en         ruler               ttyfast
  filetype=cpp      nomodeline            syntax=cpp          ttymouse=sgr
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  printoptions=paper:a4
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/aftersuffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
```

Comment: Please add proper formatting to your question. Also, for file encoding issues, we'd probably need a hex dump of the file contents to analyze what's the right encoding (if you don't know it yourself), or at least the desired and actual detected encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough just to set encoding. You have to re-read the file with a proper encoding:

```
:ed ++enc=utf-8
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and then saved the file. Sadly, it did not work.

Comment: In my case it worked perfectly, this answer is valuable!